# Castle Windsor's transient objects and .NEt 4.0's Parellel.For<>()

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, task-parallel-library, castle

I have a complex Abstract syntax tree parser / generator implemented using ANTLR and I have maintained each node's state as transient windsor objects. So before parser starts, i do container.Install(FromXml) where its a big XML of each state which is going to be used in a tree parser.

problem is i am sequentially going down the tree atleast 30 levels with very heavy housekeeping state objects for a tabular data for 2000 rows for 200 fields each row so as an attemp to reduce time, i am trying to leverage .NET's parellel for loops as:

```
// for each row 
Parellel.For(0, N (i) => 
{ 
   // for each column 
   Parellel.For(0, N, (i) => 
   { 
      // use (i) in constructing a XML node tree using windsor container invoked states for       
      each node. 
   } 
});
```

but the point i switched to Parellel.For versus traditional for loop i started getting errors in state, my tracking counters, backtracking dictionaries are clashing saying already invoked states and what not.

my container itself is wrapped in a singleton, does it matter? the objects are created on the fly in transient so wouldnt every call to container.resolve() create new objects to me. would two thread working between a resolve() and release() call matter as each should be with its own state object??

Comment: We need much more information than this.  Generally, you can't just take a `for` loop and then change it to `Parallel.For` if you're accessing state *outside* of the loop (which you are, when you say tracking counters, backtracking dictionaries, etc.).  You need to indicate what those resources are in order to define the problem.